# Regex to match ISO languages ISO

Tags: regex

I have the following languages or language locale codes in a URL and i am trying to identify through REGEX. I was partially successful in identifying them but it is failing for some scenarios

Languages that i am testing with

- en-us -- Passes
- us  -- Fails

Here is the REGEX that i have

```
([a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2}\/)c\/(deals-and-tips\/)?
```

For instance:

- https://forum.leasehackr.com/en-us/c/deals-and-tips (passes)
- https://forum.leasehackr.com/us/c/deals-and-tips (fails)

What am I missing in the above REGEX?

Comment: From what I can tell, you're not missing anything; your first string passes and your second string fails. What language are you coding this in, and why do you believe your regex isn't working as expected?

Comment: Can't you just use `([a-zA-Z]{2}(?:-[a-zA-Z]{2})?\/)c\/(deals-and-tips\/)?`? Edit: It fixes your issue because the first possibility you accepted was missing a forward slash. Replace the `\/)c\/` part with `)\/c\/` maybe. I don't think including the slash in the capture is significant.

Comment: @ObsidianAge - I'm testing it for some IIS redirects: https://regex101.com/r/b63NE1/1  and it didn't work.

Comment: @LJISAM - Thank you. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you wanted is:

```
([a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2})\/c\/(deals-and-tips\/)?
```

The difference from your regex is that I moved the first `\/` from inside the parenthesis to outside (to sit with `c\/`).

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/DhTLsD/1).

Answer (score 1):

The last `/` fails the match in any case since your urls doesn't have it, in any way I would rewrite your regex as this: `([a-zA-Z]{2})(-[a-zA-Z]{2})?\/c\/(deals-and-tips)?`. 
This way it always looks for the first part (`en`) and consider the second (`-us`) as optional.

Alternatively use `(\w{2})(-\w{2})?\/c\/(deals-and-tips)?`, if you don't mind risking to match underscores and similar simbols

Answer (score 0):

The reason your pattern does not match `us` is because the alternation `([a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2}\/)` only matches the `\/` in the second part of the alternation.

Also it does not match the last group with deals-and-tips because there is no trailing `\/` in the example data.

Your updated pattern might look like

```
([a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2})\/c\/(deals-and-tips)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w9QkVR/1)

You could shorten the pattern a bit by using an optional non capturing group `(?:-[a-zA-Z]{2})?` inside the first capturing group to optionally match the part starting with a hyphen.

As in the example data you could match the leading `\/` in front of the capturing group to get a more efficient match.

```
\/([a-zA-Z]{2}(?:-[a-zA-Z]{2})?)\/c\/(deals-and-tips)?
```

In parts

- `\/` To be a bit more precise, match the leading `/`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[a-zA-Z]{2}` Match 2 chars a-z
  - `(?:-[a-zA-Z]{2})?` Optionally match `-` and 2 chars a-z
- `)` Close group
- `\/c\/` Match `/c/`deals-and-tips`
- `(deals-and-tips)?` Optional capture **group 2** match `deals-and-tips`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ycfNsl/1)

Note that if you use another delimiter than `/` you don't have to escape the forward slash.